# Find the coordinates of $P, Q, R$.

Tags: coordinate-systems

In triangle $PQR$, $A(-2,3), B(5,-1)$ and $C(-4,-7)$ are the midpoints of $PQ, QR$ and $PR$ respectively. Find the coordinates of P, Q and R.

I really can't understand how to begin....Please hint :'(

Comment: Use the midpoint formula to write the midpoints in terms of the vertices, coordinatewise. This gives you a linear system to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x_{p}= x_{a} + x_{c}- x_{b}= -11$$
$$x_{q}= x_{a} + x_{b}- x_{c}= 7$$
$$x_{r}= x_{b} + x_{c}- x_{a}= 3$$

$$y_{p}= y_{a} + y_{c}- y_{b}= -3$$
$$y_{q}= y_{a} + y_{b}- y_{c}= 9$$
$$y_{r}= y_{b} + y_{c}- y_{a}= -11$$

P(-11,-3)

Q(7,9)

R(3,-11)

Comment: are these the formulas to solve every same kind of problem?

Comment: of course yes! for the same kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If we denote $P$ as $(x_{P},y_{P})$ and similarly
for the other coordinates then since $A$ is the mid point of two
of the sides of the triangle, say $P,Q$ then $$x_{A}=-2=\frac{x_{P}+x_{Q}}{2}$$
is the average of the $x$ values of the two sides.

Similarly $$y_{A}=3=\frac{y_{P}+y_{Q}}{2}$$

Write the other equations and solve for $x_A,y_A$ and for the $B,C$ values as well

Answer (score 1):

$P=A+(C-B)$, $Q=A+(A-P)$ and $R=B+(B-Q)$.

[image]